# How to install a specific version of HDF5 with Luarocks?

Tags: lua, hdf5, luarocks

OS: Linux Ubuntu Server 18.04

I installed hdf5 with `luarocks install hdf5` and get this error:

```
/lua/5.1/hdf5/ffi.lua:71: Unsupported HDF5 version: 1.10.0
```

How do I install a specific lower version, for example `1.8.16` ?

Comment: This solution worked for me https://github.com/deepmind/torch-hdf5/issues/76#issuecomment-357379520

Answer (score 2):

I was having issue with luasocket.
So, installed specific version using

```
luarocks install luasocket 3.0rc1
```

Note: Please first uninstall it.

**OR**

you can get latest version using git

https://peter.colberg.org/lua-hdf5/install#installing-from-git